# Encrypt des-ede3-cbc nodejs

Tags: node.js, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a string with des-ede3-cbc algorithm

My base64 password is `sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7`, the message I want to encrypt is `06080232580` the result I should have in hexadecimal is `a5334014a4f010c8779cef789886c123`

First try

```js
const iv = Buffer.alloc(8);
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', Buffer.from('sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7', 'base64'), iv);
let ciph = cipher.update('06080232580', 'utf8', 'hex');
ciph += cipher.final('hex');
console.log(ciph);
```

The result is `a5334014a4f010c8300101ae242354de`

An other test

```js
let shortkey = Buffer.from('06080232580', 'utf8');
let key = Buffer.alloc(24);
key.fill('\0');
for (i = 0; i < shortkey.length; i++) {
    key[i] = shortkey[i];
}
let IV = Buffer.alloc(8);
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', key, IV);
password = Buffer.from('sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7', 'base64');

let encryptedArr = [cipher.update(password)];
encryptedArr.push(cipher.final());
encrypted = Buffer.concat(encryptedArr);
console.log(encrypted.toString('hex'));
```

The result is `6f6b59b6c3ea45592bedbd86db4f31cc5da23d85e2ff773940aaa39e2efdc4ae`

Y have my old code working in php

```php
<?php
$message = "06080232580";
$key = base64_decode("sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7");
$l = ceil(strlen($message) / 8) * 8;
$message = $message.str_repeat("\0", $l - strlen($message));
$result = substr(openssl_encrypt($message, 'des-ede3-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"), 0, $l);
echo implode(unpack("H*", $result));
```

The result id `a5334014a4f010c8779cef789886c123`

Comment: The PHP code uses zero padding, the NodeJS code PKCS7 by default. Disable default padding in the upper NodeJS code with `cipher.setAutoPadding(false)` and implement [zero padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding) yourself.

Comment: @Topaco, thanks for your help, in the second test, the conversion from `shortkey` to `key` is not the zero padding ? Thanks

Comment: In the 2nd snippet the plaintext is used as key and vice versa. Also, it does not implement the padding from the PHP code, (_generically_ zero padding to nearest multiple of 8).

Comment: Thanks it worked inverting key and password and using a buffer of 16

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```js
    let shortkey = Buffer.from('06080232580', 'utf8');
    let key = Buffer.alloc(16);
    key.fill('\0');
    for (i = 0; i < shortkey.length; i++) {
        key[i] = shortkey[i];
    }
    let IV = Buffer.alloc(8);
    const password = Buffer.from('sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7', 'base64');
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', password, IV);
    cipher.setAutoPadding(false)
    let encryptedArr = [cipher.update(key)];
    encryptedArr.push(cipher.final());
    encrypted = Buffer.concat(encryptedArr);
    console.log(encrypted.toString('hex'));
```

Comment: Works only for plaintexts that are between 9 and 16 bytes in size (which may be sufficient for the OP, but does not work in general). Also, a static IV is insecure.